# soap webservice php client parameters initialization

Tags: php, soap

i have a problem when i am calling a remote methode using initilized variable as parameter then i get nothing in resutl, but when i pass a value as parameter everything work fine ! here is the code in php:

```
$serviceWsdl = 'http://localhost:8080/Test/services/Test?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($serviceWsdl);

function getFirstName($code){
    $firstname = $client->getFirstName(array('code' => $code));
    return $firstname->return;
}

$c=1;
$result=getFirstName($c);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read a bit about [scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in PHP. Your variable `client` is not set in your function because that is another scope. There are some solutions to handle that. You can get the variable with `global` but that is not really cool.

```
function getFirstName($code){
    global $client;
    $firstname = $client->getFirstName(array('code' => $code));
    return $firstname->return;
}
```

You shouldn't do that. When you work with globals you don't know where your variable come from.

Another solution is to define your variable as function parameter.

```
function getFirstName($code, $client) {
```

thats much better. If you work with classes you can define the variable as class variable thats much better. For example:

```
class ApiConnection {
    private $serviceWsdl = 'http://localhost:8080/Test/services/Test?wsdl';
    private $client;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->client = new SoapClient($this->serviceWsdl);
    }

    public function getFirstName($code){
        $firstname = $this->client->getFirstName(array('code' => $code));
        return $firstname->return;
    }
}
```

i haven't tested that code but its much better to work with classes.

Comment: thank you man ... the problem is resolved .. it's long time i did not code in php -_- ... sometimes simple things makes things looks hard